# PHP Swift parsing data

Tags: php, json, swift, xcode, parsing

Here is my php file for getting the data of the login successful.

I came from android and I can't get this code to work can someone help me get the data from the php? :(

```
<?php

#CHECK IF REQUEST METHOD IS POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    #INCLUDE DATABASE CONNECTION FILE
    include("connection.php");

    #CREATE CONNECTION
    $connection = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPassword, $DatabaseName);
    if ($connection -> connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed: " . $connection -> connect_error);
    }

    #FETCH ALL POST DATA AND ASSIGN TO THEIR RESPECTIVE VARIABLES
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["password"]);

    #FILTER DATABASE WITH USERNAME AND PASSWORD FROM THE POST REQUEST
    $selectUserSQL = "SELECT * FROM tableusers WHERE Username='".$username."' AND PASSWORD='".$password."' AND UserType='Faculty'";

    #EXECUTE QUERY AND COUNT ROW RESULTS
    $sqlLoginResult = $connection -> query($selectUserSQL);

    try {
        if ($sqlLoginResult -> num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rows[] = $sqlLoginResult -> fetch_assoc()) {
                $arrayLoginResult = array('LoginResult' => $rows);
            }
            echo "Login Successful";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
    } finally {
        #CLOSE CONNECTION
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

 }

?>
```

i want to parse the echo login successful here is my swift code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://norm123-001-site1.atempurl.com/UPACS%20UOP/PHP%20Files/login.php?fbclid=IwAR2lmbLYkch6JC-VL4HOI-eZuUelIwB1PUnHT1GTk4yNRrFbeBVEBDkrasY") else { return }

        let parameters=[
            "username":username_txtfld.text!,
            "password":password_txtfld.text!
        ]

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print (response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                }catch{
                    print("does not work")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

how do I make it work so I could login on my app the php file is from an android based php

Comment: Could you explain why your code does not work? Does the php script fail? the swift code? What errors do you get?

Comment: It may be failing because of the `Content-Type` of response is not JSON but you're using trying to parse it as a JSON.

Comment: When I run your swift code the response's `Content-Type` is `text/html`. So `JSONSerialization` was not working.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: what do I do now? what should I use instead of json seriliazation because my php will echo either 

login sucess or login fail it would just echo

Comment: You can try creating `String` from the data recieved. String has an init method with parameters as `Data` and encoding.